# What is 'individual falls' here?

Tags: meaning

What is 'falls' or 'individual falls' here? It is difficult for me to find the right word for 'falls' which has many meanings.

> I think they convincingly showed that genetically this **individual
>   falls** halfway between the Neanderthal and Denisovan fossils found in
>   the same cave,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to fall [somewhere] between x and y means:

to come somewhere between x and y. It is used with time periods.

Of course, you would have to know when the Neanderthals were running around and when the Denisovans were running around. The time periods. The text assumes you know the  time periods of those two categories of the genus homo.

His birthday seems **to fall between a Friday and Monday**, every year. Isn't that amazing?

to fall, to come at a certain time or place in time or on a graph.

to fall is also used with graphs to designate where some amount or numerical value is located.

Answer (score 0):

- > 2 falls between 1 and 3 on a ruler.
- > This model falls between the base model and the luxury model.

On any sort of *continuum*, to **fall** means to occupy a specific place on the continuum.